# Spotfire Between two values calculated column

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a Calculated Column see syntax below.

What I trying to achieve is this. If there is a piece of text in `[Part of Group ?]` and there is RUBU or CABU in `[ISPG Grouped]` column then get 10% of `[Final]` column. But what I also want to say is that if there is no text in `[Part of Group ?]` and and there is RUBU in `[ISPG Grouped]` column and the value of `[Final]` column is between 10,000 euro and 34,999 then get 4% of `[Final]` column

Here is the syntax I have so far

```
CASE  WHEN ([Part of Group ?]!="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") THEN [Final] / 100 * 10 
WHEN ([Part of Group ?]!="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="CABU") THEN [Final] / 100 * 10
WHEN ([Part of Group ?] ="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") AND [Final] <> 10000 34999 THEN [Final] / 100 * 4
ELSE NULL END
```

The error is happening after 34,999 see Pic 1 below for more details

Basically I don't know how to do the If In between two values then execute function :-)

Pic 1:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

"... the value of [Final] column is between 10,000 euro and 34,999 ..."

Could you change that part of your formula to this:
`... AND [Final] > 10000 AND [Final] < 34999 THEN ...`

If you want it to be inclusive, either change the operators to `<=` and `>=` or increment the numbers down and up 1 respectively.

Comment: Hi Mark P. Thank you for the assistance it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mark. Sorry but I have type in the syntax as follows `CASE  WHEN ([Part of Group ?]="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") AND ([Final]>=10000) AND ([Final]<=34999) THEN [Final] / 100 * 4 ELSE NULL END` and still I am not getting the response I want. The formula has now errors but there is no value in the new column I created. see new pic

Comment: Can you look at the other columns and see if they are causing the case to exit as `NULL` for some reason? Is there a record that satisfies this condition?

Comment: Hi Mark P: Yes there is a record that satisfies this condition C000096 has over 15,000 in RUBU and is not part of a group so it should give me back and an answer, but still nothing appearing in the new column.

Comment: Try this: `CASE WHEN ([Part of Group ?] ="" AND [ISPG Grouped]="RUBU" AND [Final] <= 10000 AND [Final] >= 34999) THEN [Final] / 100 * 4
WHEN ([Part of Group ?]!="" AND [ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") THEN [Final] / 100 * 10 
WHEN ([Part of Group ?]!="" AND [ISPG Grouped]="CABU") THEN [Final] / 100 * 10
ELSE NULL
END`

The order of things in the case statement matter. The first part of that statement could have been getting the record that the last part should have been getting.

Comment: @PhilipConnell Can you verify that there is no white space in the "ISPG Grouped" or "Part of Group ?" columns for that record?

Comment: Your answer fixes the error, +1. I answered on why they aren't getting expected results. Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Mark P's answer will address the syntax error, but you have a flaw in your `CASE` logic. `CASE` expressions will exit once a condition is met. It doesn't check the rest of the conditions, so the *order* of your conditions matter here.

The first line: `WHEN ([Part of Group ?]!="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") THEN` will cause the last line to **NEVER** be evaluated because it contains the same minimal conditions and would exit. To fix this, swap them.

```
CASE  
    WHEN ([Part of Group ?]!="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="CABU") THEN [Final] / 100 * 10
    WHEN ([Part of Group ?] ="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") AND [Final] > 10000 AND [Final] < 34999 THEN [Final] / 100 * 4
    WHEN ([Part of Group ?]!="") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") THEN [Final] / 100 * 10 
ELSE NULL END
```

As you can see here, the second condition is more restrictive than the third thus some cases would fail here, but evaluate to true for the third case.

If you put `when 1=1 then 1` at the top of your `CASE` expression, then the only value you'd ever see is 1. Similarly, if you placed it last... this would be equivalent to saying `ELSE 1` since 1 always equals 1, on earth :)

Comment: Yep, exactly. This is what I was trying to say with my last comment above. Thanks for putting it a different form. Hopefully it helps the OP!

Comment: HI Simon and Mark: Sorry for the late reply, and thank you for responding. I have entered Simons code and still i receive blanks. I believe it is because the line amount is well below the parameters of 10,000 and 34999 I think a SUM of final should be in the syntax somewhere but I am unsure where, can you have a look at the syntax, what I think it needs is WHEN SUM OF FINAL is between 10,000 and 34,999 then /100 * 4

Comment: @PhilipConnell you probably want sum of final OVER x rows?

Comment: @Simon:The OVER and SUM route didn't seem to work either. I have even simplified the syntax and still no result. The simplified syntax is `CASE  
    WHEN ([Part of Group ?]="Not In Group") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") AND ([New Sales Value]>=22000) THEN [New Sales Value] / 100 * 5 ELSE NULL END` Still no result. Sorry for the late reply I was on annual leave.

Comment: Which sum over function did you use @PhilipConnell

Comment: Hi Simon again sorry for the delay: here is an example of me using the Sum function to try and solve the issue. `CASE  
    WHEN ([Part of Group ?]="Not In Group") AND ([ISPG Grouped]="RUBU") AND Sum([New Sales Value])>=22000 THEN Sum([New Sales Value] / 100 * 5) ELSE NULL END` I assume I am using the incorrect sum function should it be value or total? Again thank you for your continued support